# Block submitting the order without filled all inputs?

Tags: javascript, php, html

is there a way how can I warn the user when he clicks the submit button (which has its action PHP in different file) that he didn't fill all inputs (instead of submitting empty field) and make him stay on that page and correct it (althought the action php is in different file)? Thank you

Comment: you can use any jquery form validation plugin

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No JavaScript necessary! Just use the HTML5 `required` attribute:

```
<input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Enter your username" required />
```

Obviously, you're going to have to validate it server-side as well, since the user can change this code using Inspect Element of Firebug. But that's easy enough:

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['username') && $_POST['username'] != '') {
    // Passed
} else {
    // Failed
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this javascript code

```
<SCRIPT>
function sub()
    {
    var usrname=document.getElementById("username").value;
    usrname=usrname.replace(/ /g,""); //for checking user isnt just entering spaces
    if(usrname!="")
    {
    document.getElementById("frm").submit();
    }
    }
</SCRIPT>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/RhLyE/3/

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can handle the onsubmit event of the form. see [here](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_form_validation.asp). Your php action script could still receive invalid data if the browser has javascript deactivated though.